# Why do sun emit light of different frequencies?

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, sun

[The sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun) emits white light, which is a mixture of light from all frequencies. Instead, it should have emitted a beam of light of the same frequency, as the source is the same?

So, can you please explain why the sun emits light in all frequencies?

Comment: Have you looked here: @ https://www.sciencefocus.com/science/what-colour-is-the-sun

Comment: Welcome to SE. I do not understand the logic "should have emitted a beam of light of the same frequency, as the source is the same".

Comment: Most of the light from the sun is [_black body radiation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) from the upper layers of its "atmosphere."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the Sun’s emission spectrum shaped like this?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772736/)

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645671/ https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59213/ https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167787/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The light sources are excited atoms subject to violent agitation. That level of agitation exists in a *distribution* with some atoms being shaken more violently than others. This means the emitted light will exist in a *distribution* of frequencies given by the blackbody formula.

This is a universal law obeyed by most hot objects (like tungsten filament light bulbs, or the cosmic microwave background for example) in the absence of other effects.

Comment: "This is a universal law obeyed by all hot objects." A counter-example would be the Sun's corona which certainly doesn't have a blackbody spectrum.

Comment: @ProfRob, will edit. -nn